# react-data-table-component add on hover title in headers name

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

I need to add more information in react data table component name.
i use this component : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component
How can i do that .
I try it this code but it doesn't work :

```
  {
            name: () => return (
                <OverlayTrigger
                placement="right"
                delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
                overlay={renderTooltip}
              >
                <span >Hover me to see</span>
              </OverlayTrigger>,
            )
            selector: "name",
            sortable: true,

        },
```

Comment: Hi! can you explain a little bit better what you want? a tooltip on the columns?

Comment: You can find the response here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71208566/how-to-show-tooltip-in-react-data-table-component/72746440#72746440

Answer (score 0):

Use it defrete no need to apply arrow function, use use this way.

```
   {
    name: <> <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" checked{true} 
    onChange{onchangeMethod()} /> &nbsp; <label>Prueba</label> </>,
    selector: "name",
    sortable: true,
   },
```